# how can I figure out what version of ember a site is running?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, devtools

If I navigate to a site that is using Ember, is there anyway for me to get the version information? I have access to the console and dev tools but this is for a production build without sourcemaps, etc...

Thanks!

Comment: production sites typically minify their scripts, which some remove comments. You can check the script source and see if it's at the top, but they usually don't have a variable with the version number

Comment: Actually it's not uncommon to have the version number carried with the library/framework. In this case it's `Ember.VERSION`. For jQuery, it's `jQuery.fn.jquery`.

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong, because I got no experience in Ember, but if you have access to the console, isn't it enough to make use of `Ember.VERSION`?

Answer (score 3):

You can find your versioning under console's tab "Debug"

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to spy on production sites that should have all of their source built for release. So, those helpful debug statements are there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Ember` should be available in the console.

[image]

In addition, if you have Chrome's [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) plugin installed, it has an option to show the Ember logo in the URL bar when a site is running Ember.

[image]